# SQL Query to sum two rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which returns result like below:

```
GRP_NAME   ACCT_COUNT
CLS         1
CMC         2
CNV         7
CON        11
COR        16
```

You can assume it like

```
SELECT GRP_NAME, ACCT_COUNT from A;
```

Now my requirement is, for first and second row, I wanna show them together and I also want to add their `ACCT_COUNT`.
So result will be something like this

```
CLS-CMC      3
CNV          7
CON         11
COR         16
```

I want to do this in my SQL query itself. Can you please suggest!! Thanks.

Comment: Based on what condition you want to group these data?

Answer (score 3):

Use a case statement and aggregates.  This assumes that it is always CLS 1 and CMC 2 that you want to group together.  if there is some other grouping mechanism in the database then we may be able to join to it and group based on it however, that information hasn't been provided in the original question.  So... given what we know... this is how it could be done.

```
SELECT case WHEN grp_name in ('CLS','CMC')  
    then 'CLS-CMC' 
    else grp_name end as GRP_NAME, 
    sum(acct_Count) as Acct_Count
FROM A
GROUP BY case WHEN grp_name in ('CLS','CMC') 
     then 'CLS-CMC' 
     else grp_name end
```

Comment: i think you misunderstood the question. There's nothing like: `CLS 1`. There are two fields: `GRP_NAME`, `ACCT_COUNT`. Got it?

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  @MaciejLos the CLS 1 is data.  It should have been CLS and CMC as Gordon corrected to.  But fundamentally this should work.  It substitutes CLS-CMC for CLS and CMC when encountered then aggregates the data and sums the account_counts. yielding desired results.  However without structure this is HARD Coded data; not generally a good idea, but given the question doesn't provide a mechanism to group the assumption is hard coding would be acceptable.